# How to import an Eclipse workspace with a complicated lib structure into Android Studio?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, gradle

I have several apps and these apps are using several library projects together.
So I have 15 library projects that are included 20 different app projects.

When I tried to move to Android Studio from Eclipse, Android Studio tried to copy those 15 libs to every single app project, which was a mess - that is why I continued with Eclipse.

Now moving to Android Studio is unavoidable and I really don't know how to preserve my lib structure in Android Studio like in Eclipse.
It was damn simple in Eclipse, you could mark a project as lib and then you could include it to any other project without copying source files.

Is this possible on Android Studio?
If so, could you please explain me how?

Note: The Lib structure is a little bit complicated.
for insance, some libs are using other libs etc.

Comment: Off course yes. In `Android studio` you can create a `Module(Just Lib)` and use it in any projects

Comment: Is there any chance that Android Studio would auto detect those modules, or do I have to create every single project in android studio again?

Answer (score 1):

Also in Android Studio you can use a library module without copying the source in different projects.
Also migrating the projects from Eclipse to Android Studio check if you can replace same libs or jar with maven dependencies. It would be easy to migrate.

Here some steps to follow to include the same library in more projects.

You can specify in your `settings.gradle` a relative path using the `project().projectDir` property, something like this:

```
 include ':lib'
 project(':lib').projectDir = new File('xxxxxx') // Relative file path from your settings.gradle
```

In this way you can use the lib module inside a project without cloning the code.

To mark a module as a library you have just to apply the right plugin in the `build.gradle` (of the module).

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

**Example:**

```
    Project0
    |--library
    |----build.gradle
    |build.gradle
    |settings.gradle

    Project1
    |--app
    |----build.gradle
    |build.gradle
    |settings.gradle
```

in `Project1/settings.gradle`

```
include ':library'
project(':library').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../Project0/library')
```

**Pay attetion**: you have to refer the `library` folder inside `Project0`, not the root folder of Project0.

in `Project1/app/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
   compile project(':library')
}
```

Comment: I tried to test your solution, created two new projects and applied your solution step by step. I got "Error: Configuration with name 'default' not found in Android Studio" at final stage when I add      compile project(':library') line.

Comment: You are using the `android` block in a top-level `build.gradle` file or you are referring the project to main root of `Project0` instead of `Project0/library`.

Comment: thank you for your answer, top-level `build.gradle` is not modified and ther e is no `android` block in it. my Project itself is a library so I put it like this,    

`include ':Project0'
project(':Project0').projectDir = new File('../Project0/')`